# Access Database created with DBContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

recently i started to learn C# and ASP.NET Core for a new job, as part of the practice i created a small api for CRUD operation that includes a database, i have created the DB using the entity framework core. I wanted to figure out how does this DB created and all of the tables in it because in the code i did not mention any tables name or something.. ? and one more thing is can i access this DB using SSMS or some other GUI to actually see the data ?
Note: I am using Visual Studio 2019

```
namespace TodoApi.Models
{
    public class TodoContext : DbContext
    {
        public TodoContext(DbContextOptions<TodoContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {}

        public DbSet<TodoItem> TodoItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
 services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(opt =>
       opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("TodoList"));
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: From the code snippet you've posted by itself, we can't really answer because we don't know how the `DbContextOptions<TodoContext>` has been configured. How is EntityFramework being configured in your `Startup` class?

Comment: @MartinCostello Thank you, i added another code snippet with the code from "Startup.cs" file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you're using an [in-memory database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli). This means that's it's ultimately all stored in memory in the application. That means there will be no files on disk, and no way to access it remotely using a tool like SSMS. That's also why you don't need to specify a table name etc., because it's not needed for an in-memory database because it's kind of just a fancy way of storing all the data in an array, as a simple analogy. The in-memory provider's primary usage is for testing.

If you want to be able to view the contents of the database in a tool such as SSMS, you'll need to use the [SQL Server provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) (which will require a connection string etc.), which would be configured with `opt.UseSqlServer(...)`. Alternatively if you didn't want to use SQL Server, you could use the [SQLite provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli).

Documentation about the different providers available can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli).

Comment: Thank you very much, now i understand.. All of this is new for me (coming from Node.js world).